# ios navigation error using button

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to go from  login screen to signup. But getting error...

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a
>   nil modal view controller on target .'

Login.H

```
#import "SignupController.h"

@interface LoginController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet SignupController *signupController;
```

Login.M

```
(IBAction)signup:(UIButton*) sender
{
    NSLog(@"lla"); 
        [self presentModalViewController:signupController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: The error message seems to tell you al you need : the view controller you're trying to present (`signupController`) is nil. Do you instantiate it somewhere before trying to load it?!

Answer (score 2):

you need to allocate and initiate your signupController first.

```
self.signupController = [[SignupController alloc]initWithNibName:xibname];
[self presentModalViewController:signupController animated:YES];
```

wheras `xibname` is will be the name of your nibfile, somthing like @"signupController"
if your interface file is called `signupController.xib`

sebastian

Answer (score 1):

if you donot use a nib file:

```
signupController = [[SignupController  alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:signupController animated:YES];
```

if you use a nib file:

```
signupController = [[SignupController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"nib file name with out ext" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:signupController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Even if the answer is quite obvious for some of us, some words to go with your two lines of code would't be too much..

Comment: Get it :) , and I'll finish it.

Comment: Even if you're not using a nib, you should still call `initWithNibName:bundle:` with nil arguments.